# Where I can find HL7 FHIR ECoreDefinitions.xml for for versions different from DSTU 2?

Tags: hl7-fhir

I am working on a Command Line Interface in Python for HL7 FHIR and I am looking for ECoreDefinitions.xml file for version different from DSTU 2. I know ECoreDefinitions.xml DSTU 2 is at http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/fhir/ecoredefinitions.xml, but I'm not able to find  similar files for different FHIR versions, in particular for the upcoming 1.4.0 or the versions previous to DSTU2.

Are they available?

Answer (score 2):

No. we have removed the ecore definitions part now. You should use the files in validation.xml.zip (see "FHIR Definitions" in /downloads.html of the version you are interested in)

Comment: Thank you. Your answer solved my problem. Best regards.